# Calling a redux action inside another action is not working

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-actions, redux-reducers

i have console log the error and the error is visible in console but the **setAlert** action is not dispatching , why is that ?

This is the Auth action code

```
 import axios from "axios"
import {setAlert} from "../actions/alert";
import { REGISTER_FAIL } from "./conts"

export const register = ({ name, username, email, password }) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    const body = JSON.stringify({ name, username, email, password });

    try {
    const res =   await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/signup",body,config);
        setAlert("Email has been sent..! Please Confirm Your email","success",10000) //not working
}
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data.error);
      const error = err.response.data.error;

      setAlert(error,"error",5000); //not working

      dispatch({
          type:REGISTER_FAIL
      });
    }
}
```

this is Alert action

```
    import {SET_ALERT,REMOVE_ALERT} from "./conts";
import {v4 as uuidv4} from "uuid"; 

export const setAlert =(msg,alertType,timeOut =5000)=> dispatch=>{
    const id= uuidv4(); 
    dispatch({
        type: SET_ALERT,
        payload:{msg,alertType,id}
    });

    setTimeout(()=> dispatch({type:REMOVE_ALERT,payload:id}),timeOut)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok it seems , i just needed to dispatch the setAlerts